# C# Winforms ComboBox has strange hover behavior

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, combobox, scroll

I have a ComboBox with style DropDownList, and which is limited to displaying a maximum number of items before adding a scroll bar. Once in scroll mode, it will automatically scroll to place the hovered-over item at the top of the visible portion of the list. Here's a small example with 4 visible items. Say there are 10 items in the list and I'm here:

```
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5 <-- cursor hovering here, item selected (not committed)
Item 6
```

After roughly half a second (probably less), the ComboBox autoscrolls so that my visible items look like this:

```
Item 5 <-- item selected (not committed)
Item 6
Item 7 <-- cursor still hovering here, item not selected
Item 8
```

This behavior is extremely annoying as it makes it very difficult to scroll through the items (especially up). Is there some property that sets this behavior?

Comment: No repro. Might be your Windows/accessibility/mouse driver settings?

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot. I posted my "solution" below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I screwed up somewhere else and was repeatedly refreshing the ComboBox. I have some logic to refresh the combo box when a certain rare event occurs, and it turns out that the code that fires the event was buggy and was actually firing it every second.